# What does "would" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, conditionals

What does this mean?

> What would you do if I come to your Clinic?

This makes me confused because I can not understand is it first or second conditional or even is it a conditional?  Please explain.

In general, what does *would* mean when it is used with present time?

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing, and I'm not sure if they are presenting coming to the clinic as a possible or as a counterfactual.

I suspect that the speaker started off intending a counterfactual (I think that is what EFL teachers mean by "second conditional") and then changed their mind half way.

Comment: I agree that it is confusing. Possibly meant to say ´if I came / if I were to come to your clinic´. As for EFL terms: the second conditional is a counterfactual in the present or future. If it's past it's called third conditional. And if it's mixed, it's called mixed conditional.